# Sql injection prevention in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, dependency-injection, sql-injection

I am new to Laravel and i am learning it .

What do we do in laravel to prevent sql injection ??
What is dependency injection and what do we do to prevent that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: laravel have tons of layer to prevent it.. just do it properly and see docs.

Answer (score 3):

[SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is bad. Dependency injection is good. and its two separate things. SQL injection is an attack.  [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is a technique used in programming.

Laravel uses  [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) to build run query. So don't worry too much about sql injection unless you do it wrong way.

Read about [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container) to learn about Laravel dependency injection.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Eloquent throughout, as a general rule of thumb SQL injection won't be an issue, with one proviso.

There are Eloquent methods that enable part of a query to be written out as raw SQL, such as `whereRaw()` and `selectRaw()`. If you use these and pass the query as a string with the values included as is, you are vulnerable to SQL injection, as in this example:

```
whereRaw("name = '$name'")
```

However, these methods allow you to use prepared statements by passing as the second argument an array of values:

```
whereRaw("name = ?", [$name])
```

By doing that, you should be safe from SQL injection.

Dependency injection is an entirely separate subject and I'd echo aimme in pointing you to the Laravel documentation to learn more.